# Longest Increasing Subsequence Recursive version

Tags: recursion

Traditional Longest Increasing Subsequence problem.
This is recursion version ( not DP version )
I realized that version1 code had a bug, so I changed it to version2.

I don't clearly understand why version2 works and version1 has a bug for input A0

Please see version 1 and version2 below:

```
static int lis1(int[] v) {
    int maxLen = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i < v.length; i++) {
        List<Integer> w = new ArrayList<Integer>();     

        for( int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if( v[j] < v[i] ) {
                w.add(v[j]);                
            }
        }

        // it used to be the following one line which has bug for input A0
        //cand =  lis1(l2a(w)) + 1;           // version1

        // so I changed it to the following, but can't clearly understand why it works.
        // without this part, it has but for input A0
        int cand = 1;                         // version2
        if(v[i-1] < v[i])
            cand =  lis1(l2a(w)) + 1;
        else 
            cand =  lis1(l2a(w));

        maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, cand);        
    }

    return maxLen;      
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A0 = {3, 2, 5, 6};    // for this input version1 had a bug which printed out 4 ( instead of 3 )
    int[] A1 = {1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7};                            // 6
    int[] A2 = { 10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60, 80 };               // 6
    int[] A3 = { 5, 0, 4, 2, 3, 7, 1 };                             // 4
    int[] A4 = { 2, 7, 3, 4, 9, 8, 12 };                            // 5
    int[] A5 = {3, 4, 2, 5 };                                       // 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually... neither of your version works. Try putting `A0={3,2,7,6}`, your v2 returns 2, obviously wrong.

As for v1, for `v={3,2}` the answer should be 1, right? Let's see what your code does. When index `i=1`, your `w` after inner `for` loop equals `{}`. Then you made a recursive call to `w={}`, which should've returned 0, but it returns 1. Why, because of your `maxlen` variable, which is wrongly initialized with `1`. This error propagates to entire `{3,2,5,6}` and gives wrong answer.

v2 accidentally solves this problem because your `if` condition then fails `(3<2)`, and it returns the previously returned 1.

Just delete entire version 2, correct `maxlen` initialization. And start outer loop `for(int i = 1; i < v.length; i++)` with `i=0`, else you will get 0 for single-element array.

```
static int lis1(int[] v) {
int maxLen = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    List<Integer> w = new ArrayList<Integer>();     

    for( int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if( v[j] < v[i] ) {
            w.add(v[j]);                
        }
    }     
    cand =  lis1(l2a(w)) + 1;           // version1

    maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, cand);        
}

return maxLen;      
}
```